# Is it possible to user multiple custom user model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make **custom user model with AbstarcBaseUer** in django 3.1.
There are **two types of user** in my app. Reader, Publisher.
Each model should have different fields, so I decided to make two tables for each.
First I made Parent class for them, named `User` which **inherit from AbstractBaseUser**.

```
class User(AbstarctBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # and some other fields and setting
```

Second I made `Reader` and `Publisher` class which **inherit from User class**.

```
class Reader(User):
    # for Reader model Fields
class Publisher(User):
    # for Publisher model Fields
```

Is this structure available in django?
And if it is, how do I override `UserManger` for these?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this, it works perfectly unlike using the boolean type whic attimes breaks

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "Publisher"), (2, "Reader"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Publisher(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Don't forget to add the AUTH_USER_MODEL=YOURAPPNAME.CustomUser

As for the UserManager, you can leave it alone except you want to customize into some other things.

You can learn more using this link, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

This should do the trick, if oyur need more clarification, please do let me know